# Python bs4 find /n instead wanted text

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to scrape a website using requests and bs4, T tried to get the 'title' of `msgProdStockOut`, I used `soup.find` to find `id = prodMainImg` but it returns `/n` and nothing in `msgProdStockOut`.

Is there a way to get the `title` in `msgProdStockOut` directly?

[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jp[enter image description here]g)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.gu-global.com/tw/store/goods/325571'
r = requests.get(my_url).content
soup = soup(r, 'html.parser') 

soup.find(id = 'msgProdStockOut')
#None
soup.find(id = 'prodMainImg ').text
#u'/n'
```

Comment: If you visit the source page of the website, you see that this tag doesnt exist! That is, this isn't possible with requests.